# Returning NotMapped field through breeze

Tags: asp.net-mvc, breeze, entity-framework-6

I have a  model that returns a calculated color field like the following:

```
[NotMapped]
    public string ColorHex
    {
        get
        {
            if (!colorInt) return "";

            var c = ColorTranslator.FromOle(colorInt);

            return "#" + c.R.ToString("X2") + c.G.ToString("X2") + c.B.ToString("X2");
        }
        set
        {
            var color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(value);

            colorInt = ColorTranslator.ToOle(color);

        }
    }
```

The ColorInt property is just a property that maps to the database. But when I get the entity with breeze like the following:

```
 return manager.fetchEntityByKey(
                entitySetDefinition.entityType, id, true)
                .then(fetchSucceeded)
                .fail(queryFailed);
```

It ignores the "NotMapped" columns. How can I make it not do that?

I need to return some columns that aren't mapped with the entity. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at the section of the docs on NotMapped properties?

Comment: No, do you have a link to the specific document? I couldn't find anything that specific.

Comment: read through this - http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities and this - http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/entity-serialization